# Giraph best's Vertex Input format, for an input file with ids of type String

Tags: hadoop, giraph

I have a multinode giraph cluster working properly in my PC. I executed the SimpleShortestPathExample from Giraph and was executed fine.

This algorithm was ran with this file (tiny_graph.txt):

```
[0,0,[[1,1],[3,3]]]
[1,0,[[0,1],[2,2],[3,1]]]
[2,0,[[1,2],[4,4]]]
[3,0,[[0,3],[1,1],[4,4]]]
[4,0,[[3,4],[2,4]]]
```

This file has the following input format:

```
[source_id,source_value,[[dest_id, edge_value],...]]
```

Now, I’m trying to execute this same algorithm, in this same cluster, but with an input file different from the original. My own file is like this:

```
[Portada,0,[[Sugerencias para la cita del día,1]]]
[Proverbios españoles,0,[]]
[Neil Armstrong,0,[[Luna,1][ideal,1][verdad,1][Categoria:Ingenieros,2,[Categoria:Estadounidenses,2][Categoria:Astronautas,2]]]
[Categoria:Ingenieros,1,[[Neil Armstrong,2]]]
[Categoria:Estadounidenses,1,[[Neil Armstrong,2]]]
[Categoria:Astronautas,1,[[Neil Armstrong,2]]]
```

It's very similar to the original, but the id's are String and the vertex and edges values are Long. My question it's  which TextInputFormat should i use for this, because i already try with `org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat` and `org.apache.giraph.io.formats.TextDoubleDoubleAdjacencyListVertexInputFormat` and i couldn't get this working.

With this problem solved, i could adapt the original shortest path example algorithm and let it work for my file, but until i get a solution for this i can't reach to that point.

If this format it's not a good decision, i could adapt it maybe, but i don't know which it's my best option, my knowledge from Text Input and Output Format in giraph it's really bad, that's why i0me here asking for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this adapting my own file to fit in `org.apache.giraph.io.formats.TextDoubleDoubleAdjacencyListVertexInputFormat` . My original file should be like this:

```
Portada 0.0     Sugerencias     1.0
Proverbios      0.0
Neil    0.0     Luna    1.0     ideal   1.0     verdad  1.0     Categoria:Ingenieros    2.0     Categoria:Estadounidenses       2.0     Categoria:Astronautas   2.0
Categoria:Ingenieros    1.0     Neil    2.0
Categoria:Estadounidenses       1.0     Neil    2.0
Categoria:Astronautas   1.0     Neil    2.0
```

Those spaces between the data are tab spaces ('\t'), because this format has that option as predetermined token value for spliting the original lines into several strings.

Thanks @masoud-sagharichian for your help anyway!! :D

Answer (score 3):

It's better to write your own inputformat. I suggest use hash codes of your strings. I write a sample code such that each line consists of:
[vertex_id (integer e.g. hash code of your string), vertex_val (long), [[neighbor_id (integer), neighbor_val (long)], ....]

```
public class JsonIntLongIntLongVertexInputFormat extends
  TextVertexInputFormat<IntWritable, LongWritable, LongWritable> {

  @Override
  public TextVertexReader createVertexReader(InputSplit split,
      TaskAttemptContext context) {
    return new JsonIntLongIntLongVertexReader();
  }


  class JsonIntLongIntLongVertexReader extends
    TextVertexReaderFromEachLineProcessedHandlingExceptions<JSONArray,
    JSONException> {

    @Override
    protected JSONArray preprocessLine(Text line) throws JSONException     {
      return new JSONArray(line.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected IntWritable getId(JSONArray jsonVertex) throws JSONException,
              IOException {
      return new IntWritable(jsonVertex.getString(0).hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    protected LongWritable getValue(JSONArray jsonVertex) throws
      JSONException, IOException {
      return new LongWritable(jsonVertex.getLong(1));
    }

    @Override
    protected Iterable<Edge<IntWritable, LongWritable>> getEdges(
        JSONArray jsonVertex) throws JSONException, IOException {
      JSONArray jsonEdgeArray = jsonVertex.getJSONArray(2);
      List<Edge<IntWritable, LongWritable>> edges =
          Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(jsonEdgeArray.length());
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonEdgeArray.length(); ++i) {
        JSONArray jsonEdge = jsonEdgeArray.getJSONArray(i);
        edges.add(EdgeFactory.create(new IntWritable(jsonEdge.getString(0).hashCode()),
            new LongWritable(jsonEdge.getLong(1))));
      }
      return edges;
    }

    @Override
    protected Vertex<IntWritable, LongWritable, LongWritable>
    handleException(Text line, JSONArray jsonVertex, JSONException e) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Couldn't get vertex from line " + line, e);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for answer one of my questions Masoud, i finally went for editing my own data to fit in a  giraph format, but your answer will be very useful in the future